# RSS Feed validation issue

Tags: rss, feed, podcast

I am having an issue with my RSS feed that has not been an issue before. You can find the [feed file here](http://www.akashicsound.com/Apple/CantinaRSS.js).

I understand that a .js isnt a standard RSS enclosure, but it hasn't been an issue for feeds since I started using the tag.

I scoured it for ampersands or anything that might be causing the hangup, but nothing. Any idea what could be the cause of that problem?

Comment: you need to give more information about your problem.  Are you parsing this RSS feed? Are you getting an error? What language or library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed tag `<itunes:category text="Star Wars">`; you can use an [xml validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php) to look for errors like this.